# Change layout with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

When I start a new "Navigation Drawer" project in Android Studio there is already some code. How can I change the layout by using the Buttons in the Drawer?

The Navigation Drawer looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                tools:openDrawer="start">

                <include
                    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
                    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout >
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:context="com.orgName.myName.projectName.MainActivity">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/main_container"
                layout="@layout/content_main" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.orgName.myName.projectName.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {

            LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id. main_container);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, null);
            mainLayout.removeAllViews();
            mainLayout.addView(layout);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

            LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id. main_container);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_gallery, null);
            mainLayout.removeAllViews();
            mainLayout.addView(layout);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

            LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id. main_container);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_slideshow, null);
            mainLayout.removeAllViews();
            mainLayout.addView(layout);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

            LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id. main_container);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_manage, null);
            mainLayout.removeAllViews();
            mainLayout.addView(layout);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

            LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id. main_container);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_share, null);
            mainLayout.removeAllViews();
            mainLayout.addView(layout);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

            LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id. main_container);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_send, null);
            mainLayout.removeAllViews();
            mainLayout.addView(layout);

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't we handle every layouts with fragments?
In order to take care of all the background work that may be needed on each layouts?

Answer (score 0):

look your MainActivity XML, you will find the structure likes below:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" /> 

<!-- you can custom your layout here in LinearLayout-->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
android:layout_width="240dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" >

<!-- you can add a button here-->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="mButton"/>

</LinearLayout> 
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

you can custom your view in fragment, or instead with a  Linearlayout here and fill button in your layout.

```
 mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
 mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

 mButton = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
 mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //close DrawerLayout here
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mLinearLayout);
        }
    });
```

You can use a Fragment to replace FrameLayout：

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1 = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.content_frame,
                    overviewFragment);
            fragmentTransaction1.commit();
```

Comment: Can you give me some code how I can go from e.g. layout 1 to layout 2 by take the navigation drawer and press e.g.  button Gallery?

Comment: In your Activty ,  set a onclickListener on Button and mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mLinearLayout);